# Are there any open source examples of domain driven design?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've been reading the books and watching videos, but would love to see some real world implementations of good DDD.

Tangentially related - are there any Youtube videos of DDD projects being built from scratch, and talking through the design decisions, and iterations.

Comment: There's an open source _example_: https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core

Comment: Companies tend to invest in rich domain models in those areas where they expect to realize a competitive advantage -- which definitely reduces the likelihood that they will turn around and open source that advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some useful git repositories.

- https://github.com/thombergs/buckpal
- https://github.com/Sairyss/domain-driven-hexagon